# How to keep track of days online?

Tags: 7, views, users, nodes

I'd like to display the total number of days that users were online in a View on their profile pages.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem can be solved with a variant of [my solution for a more general problem](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/234256/16550). In particular, here are the adaptations that have to be made. Add a new user [Date](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/234256/16550) field *Last day online* that stores a day, month and year. Also create a user integer field *Total days online*. Then use the following Rule:

```
{ "rules_extra_day_online" : {
    "LABEL" : "Extra day online",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules", "rules_scheduler" ],
    "ON" : { "init" : [] },
    "IF" : [
      { "NOT user_has_role" : {
          "account" : [ "site:current-user" ],
          "roles" : { "value" : { "1" : "1" } }
        }
      },
      { "NOT data_is" : {
          "data" : [ "site:current-user:field-last-day-online" ],
          "value" : "today midnight"
        }
      }
    ],
    "DO" : [
      { "data_calc" : {
          "USING" : {
            "input_1" : [ "site:current-user:field-total-days-online" ],
            "op" : "+",
            "input_2" : "1"
          },
          "PROVIDE" : { "result" : { "new_total" : "New total" } }
        }
      },
      { "data_set" : {
          "data" : [ "site:current-user:field-total-days-online" ],
          "value" : [ "new-total" ]
        }
      },
      { "data_set" : {
          "data" : [ "site:current-user:field-last-day-online" ],
          "value" : "today midnight"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

This is what the Rule does in words:

- First, check that the current user is verified, and make sure the user's *Last day online* is not `today midnight`.
- If the above requirements are satisfied, then increase the *Total days online* by one and change the *Last day online* to `today midnight`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Visitors](https://drupal.org/project/visitors) module.

It will give you the following reports:

> View pages that have recently been visited.
> View pages that have been hit frequently.
> View pages count per month.
> View pages count per day of month.
> View pages count per day of week.
> View pages count per hour.
> View pages count per host.
> View access log.
> View user activity report (hits, nodes, comments).
> View referer list.

and many more things.

Maybe for your requirement you need some customization.

Answer (score -1):

You can take a clue form [User Stats](https://drupal.org/project/user_stats) module if it doesn't support your requirement and implement your own custom solutions to track user logged in days...

> Provides commonly requested user statistics for themers, IP address
>   tracking and Views integration. Statistics are:
>
> days registered; join date; days since last login; days since last
>   post; post count; login count; user online/offline; IP address;

Comment: As there isn't a recommended release for Drupal 7 yet, I can't really consider this as a possible solution.

Comment: The last commit has done 7 years ago. Until now, no stable release has been created for Drupal 7. The module is essentially a Drupal 6 module that was converted for Drupal 7, but that has never been completed, so far.