# How to count the number of consecutive days on which verified users accessed the website?

Tags: 7, rules, nodes

My main problem is very similar to [How to grant userpoints to users who perform a login 5 days consecutively?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/35484/how-to-grant-userpoints-to-users-who-perform-a-login-5-days-consecutively): I would like to keep track of the number of consecutive days on which verified users accessed the website. Therefore, I added an integer user field *Consecutive days* and created the following Rule that hooks into "visiting the website" (see [How to hook into "visiting the website"?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/223352/16550)):

```
{ "rules_extra_consecutive_day_online" : {
    "LABEL" : "Extra consecutive day online",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules", "rules_scheduler" ],
    "ON" : { "init" : [] },
    "IF" : [
      { "user_has_role" : {
          "account" : [ "site:current-user" ],
          "roles" : { "value" : { "2" : "2" } }
        }
      },
      { "OR" : [
          { "data_is" : {
              "data" : [ "site:current-user:field-consecutive-days" ],
              "value" : "0"
            }
          },
          { "AND" : [
              { "data_is" : {
                  "data" : [ "site:current-user:last-access" ],
                  "op" : "\u003C",
                  "value" : "today midnight -1 second"
                }
              },
              { "data_is" : {
                  "data" : [ "site:current-user:last-access" ],
                  "op" : "\u003E",
                  "value" : "yesterday midnight"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "DO" : [
      { "data_calc" : {
          "USING" : {
            "input_1" : [ "site:current-user:field-consecutive-days" ],
            "op" : "+",
            "input_2" : "1"
          },
          "PROVIDE" : { "result" : { "new_streak" : "New streak" } }
        }
      },
      { "data_set" : {
          "data" : [ "site:current-user:field-consecutive-days" ],
          "value" : [ "new-streak" ]
        }
      },
      { "schedule" : {
          "component" : "rules_reset_consecutive_days",
          "date" : "+2 days midnight",
          "param_user" : [ "site:current-user" ]
        }
      },
    ]
  }
}
```

The scheduled Rules component at the end of the Rule resets *Consecutive days* to `0` if necessary:

```
{ "rules_reset_consecutive_days" : {
    "LABEL" : "Reset consecutive days",
    "PLUGIN" : "rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules" ],
    "USES VARIABLES" : { "user" : { "label" : "User", "type" : "user" } },
    "IF" : [
      { "data_is" : {
          "data" : [ "user:last-access" ],
          "op" : "\u003C",
          "value" : "yesterday midnight -1 second"
        }
      }
    ],
    "DO" : [
      { "data_set" : {
          "data" : [ "user:field-consecutive-days" ],
          "value" : "0"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

This seems to work relatively well, but there is a catch: the *Last access* field is not updated at every page request. As a result, users can increase their *Consecutive days* during a few minutes right after midnight by refreshing the page again and again.

How can I fix this issue? Should I override the *Last access* field at every page request or is there an alternative way to correctly update *Consecutive days*?

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens: Haha, thank you for the upvote. ;-) Yes, those relative formats are like magic (see http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php).

Comment: Maybe you should post a self answered question also to illustrate some of that magic with some other Rules Example(s)? How about something with a title like "How to take advantage in Rules of relative date formats?" (+link to that php.net page). Give it some thought (and notify me if you ever do)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overriding the built-in *Last access* field is not possible with Rules, so I added a new user [Date](http://drupal.org/project/date) field *Last day online* that stores a day, month and year. Recall that I had already created another user integer field *Consecutive days*. Here is the magical Rule:

```
{ "rules_extra_consecutive_day_online" : {
    "LABEL" : "Extra consecutive day online",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules", "rules_scheduler" ],
    "ON" : { "init" : [] },
    "IF" : [
      { "NOT user_has_role" : {
          "account" : [ "site:current-user" ],
          "roles" : { "value" : { "1" : "1", "3" : "3" } }
        }
      },
      { "OR" : [
          { "data_is" : { "data" : [ "site:current-user:field-consecutive-days" ], "value" : "0" } },
          { "data_is" : {
              "data" : [ "site:current-user:field-last-day-online" ],
              "value" : "yesterday midnight"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "DO" : [
      { "data_calc" : {
          "USING" : {
            "input_1" : [ "site:current-user:field-consecutive-days" ],
            "op" : "+",
            "input_2" : "1"
          },
          "PROVIDE" : { "result" : { "new_consecutive_days" : "New consecutive days" } }
        }
      },
      { "data_set" : {
          "data" : [ "site:current-user:field-consecutive-days" ],
          "value" : [ "new-consecutive-days" ]
        }
      },
      { "data_set" : {
          "data" : [ "site:current-user:field-last-day-online" ],
          "value" : "today midnight"
        }
      },
      { "schedule" : {
          "component" : "rules_reset_consecutive_days",
          "date" : "+2 days midnight",
          "param_user" : [ "site:current-user" ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

This is what the Rule does in words:

- First, check that the current user is verified, and make sure the user's *Consecutive days* field is zero or the user's *Last day online* is yesterday.
- If the above requirements are satisfied, then increase the *Consecutive days*, change the *Last day online* to today and schedule the component *Reset consecutive days*.

Underneath is an export of the mentioned Rules component. It resets the *Consecutive days* field if the *Last day online* field is less than yesterday (which means that the user was not online on at least one day).

```
{ "rules_reset_consecutive_days" : {
    "LABEL" : "Reset consecutive days",
    "PLUGIN" : "rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules" ],
    "USES VARIABLES" : { "user" : { "label" : "User", "type" : "user" } },
    "IF" : [
      { "data_is" : {
          "data" : [ "user:field-last-day-online" ],
          "op" : "\u003C",
          "value" : "yesterday midnight"
        }
      }
    ],
    "DO" : [
      { "data_set" : { "data" : [ "user:field-consecutive-days" ], "value" : "0" } }
    ]
  }
}
```